# simplicial complexes and associated ideals

Tags: ideals, simplicial-complex

Simplicial Complexes have Stanley Reisner Ideals in Abstract Algebra. From what I understand, the ideal is generated by listing the minimal missing edges, faces, facets etc. I've drawn a few examples below and would like to see if the simplicial complex I've drawn matches the associated Stanley Reisner ideal.

[image]
[image]

Further, I know that these ideals are supposed to be monomials with positive exponents. As you can see, I can't really see how an exponent would be used in this setting. ie - in what instance would I write $w^2$ or $(uv)^3$?

Comment: Saying that "simplicial complexes have associated ideals" is not sufficient to enable an answer this question, not without knowing the nature of that association. Compare this, for example, to the statement "numbers have associated numbers". What is the definition of the association?

Comment: I think they are ideals from Stanley-Reisner rings. It sounds like this is part of my confusion? That there are many ideals?

Comment: What is your question? The Stanley-Reisner correspondence gives an equivalence between simplicial complexes and _squarefree_ monomial ideals

Comment: In example 1 I drew a complex and asked if the ideal was (uv, uvw, xyz, {}). Is this the case?

Comment: No, your ideal is not correct for example 1. The minimal generators of the Stanley-Reisner ideal are precisely the minimal nonfaces of the simplicial complex. So you don't have an empty generator (which would be the monomial $1$), because there is an empty face. Your nonface $uvw$ is not minimal, since it's a multiple of $uv$. Finally you're missing lots of minimal nonfaces, like $ux, uy, uz, \ldots$

Comment: I have edited my post with a new attempt at the S.R. ideal